# how to open a webpage using jQuery based on the search keyword word entered in a form element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to open a webpage(html file) using a html `form` element, in such a way that when I enter a `keyword` in the `text` input field and press the submit button, a new page with the keyword as document/file name should be loaded.

For example :

I will enter a keyword called `123` and I will press the submit button.  On pressing the submit button, the page should be redirected to the `123.html`

I wish to do it with `jQuery`

Comment: What's your exact question? Please post some code and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit_btn_id").click(function(){
    var page = $("#page_txtbox_id")+".html";
    location.href = page;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an example : **http://jsbin.com/ifipoy**

```
$(function() {
  $('#submit').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $('#txt').val();
    if( val !== (null || "")){
      var page = val+ ".html";
      alert("loading the page : " + page + " in 2 seconds!");
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = page;
      }, 2000);      
    }
  });
});
```